# Не срабатывает оператор switch

Tags: php, wordpress

Работаю над маленьким проектом на WP.
Проблема со срабатыванием оператора `switch` - ничего не выводится, если только это не `case(« Yefren Carrero « );`:

```
$my_bg_class = wp_get_document_title();
switch ($my_bg_class){
    case("Yefren Carrero"): 
        echo "home_bg"; break;
    case("A propos – Yefren Carrero"):
        echo "propos_bg"; break;
    case("TUTTI Maestro – Yefren Carrero"):
        echo "maestro_bg"; break;
    case("Enseignement – Yefren Carrero"):
        echo "enseignement_bg"; break;
    case("Projets – Yefren Carrero"):
        echo "projets_bg"; break;
    case("Médias – Yefren Carrero"):
        echo "media_bg"; break;
    case("Euphonium – Yefren Carrero"):
        echo "euphonium_bg"; break;
    case("CONTACTS – Yefren Carrero"):
        echo "contacts_bg"; break;
    case("Passeurs d’Arts /EL SISTEMA/ – Yefren Carrero"):
        echo "passeurs_bg"; break;
}
```

Comment: In russian, please. Вы находитесь на сайте StackOverflow на русском.

Comment: возможно нужно делать trim

Comment: или проблема из-за дефиса

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена путем замены используемой функции - вместо `wp_get_document_title()` я поставил `wp_kses_post( oceanwp_title() )`, которая возвращает название только собственно страницы, не добавляя название сайта через тире, которое в свою очередь невозможно вырезать ни `str_replace();` ни `trim();`